# Authentication failed for uid=wpadmin

Tags: websphere

I got below exception when I tried to login into websphere console

> SECJ0055E: Authentication failed for
>   uid=wpadmin,cn=users,dc=te-data,dc=core. The user id or password might
>   have been entered incorrectly or misspelled.  The user id might not
>   exist, the account could have expired or disabled.  The password might
>   have expired. [6/5/18 6:00:00:613 EET] 0000003a J2EEContext   E
>   ASYN9999E: Unexpected Exception Occurred:
>   com.ibm.websphere.asynchbeans.SerialDeserialException: Exception while
>   deserializing a saved service.  Service=security. Unable to
>   deserialize the Subjects in this Context, cause: The user is from a
>   foreign realm, defaultWIMFileBasedRealm, and this foreign realm is not
>   trusted. Current realm is ssptds.te-data.core:389

Answer (score 1):

The error is a big hint

> The user is from a foreign realm, defaultWIMFileBasedRealm, and this foreign realm is not trusted.

I found the answer [in the IBM docs](https://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg21966939):

> Go to the Websphere Application Server administration console and
>   under Security > Global security > Federated repositories make sure
>   that both the realms mentioned in the error are listed as trusted.

This is either a configuration error, or you are not supposed to login the way you are. If you have access to the administration console, the fix is just to add `defaultWIMFileBasedRealm` to the trusted realms. Otherwise you may need to log on some other way.

Comment: I trusted the both realms and now I can not start the dmgr with the following error, Please help.:    An unexpected exception occurred when attempting to authenticate the server's id during security initialization. The exception is javax.naming.AuthenticationException: [LDAP: error code 49 - Invalid Credentials]

Comment: @HishamRakha Please do not change questions after your initial one. If you have a different question post it as a different question, so you can get a proper response. This is not a forum, we can't have conversations here. If this answers your original question accept it, and post a new one. You can link it here in the comments if you want me to have a look.

Comment: this is not an new question I just followed your recommendation and now cant start the manager