# Changed realm in Websphere Application Server now JVMs will not start

Tags: ldap, websphere

We're unable to start our JVMs after changing the LDAP server in the Security -> Global Security settings.  We get "The user is from a foreign realm, XXXX:289, and this foreign realm is not trusted. Current realm is XXXX".

This error seems straightforward.  Yet we cannot find anything wrong with our settings. The "Trusted authentication realms - inbound" looks correct.  The settings in the Global Security looks right.  The users have been recreated

The process we followed was to update the LDAP server.  Remove and added back the Admin group roles so they have the new LDAP server.  Then shutdown all the Websphere processes.  Run the osgiCfgInit.sh and clearcasecache.sh scripts to clear the cache.  Then started the processes back up.

Is there a file or cache we need to modify for our admin user?

Comment: Is this question related to Realm, the relational database? If not, please remove that tag. [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50699470/authentication-failed-for-uid-wpadmin/50699787#50699787) appears to address your question.

Comment: I removed "realm", sorry for the mix up.  I read the answer you linked to and will check.  Just seems like there's some cache or something I missed because the JVM is calling the LDAP server that is no longer configured.